# How is it different from manually changing php.ini and using ini.set?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, php-ini

As, we know to change some services or adding or disabling and services we always need to restart the server in the services.
But how is it different to use ini.set function and it works without refreshing the server.

*Is it possible,that these set.ini function gets itself saved in cache and use itself for a particular operation.
Another way can be , That it uses itself like a constructor.*

**For example-**

```
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");
```

We can change that in php.ini files itself and refresh the services to run this.
But with ini_set it works without doing this ? HOW?
How, can we access that in between server and browser to alter the details of php.ini to check the security flaw.
**THANK YOU in Advance.**

Comment: [Which is better php.ini vs ini_set()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000111/which-is-better-php-ini-vs-ini-set)

Comment: **Hello Cokile**, other part of my question is , how can i access the settings of php.ini between the execution of command.

Comment: and why dont we need to **restart the services cause our server is running on previous setting** when using ini_set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is better php.ini vs ini\_set()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000111/which-is-better-php-ini-vs-ini-set)