# symfony problem with ini_set() function when uploading big files

Tags: php, symfony, ini-set

in a project created with symfony 4.4.* when uploading files i got the following error

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 12406038 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

I can fix this by changing the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size with the function `ini_set()`

my question is where to put it:

1. just after the opning of the php tag of the controller.
2. after the namespace .
3. after the use's.

or in the specific method of the controller ?

Comment: _“i can fix this by changing the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size with the function ini_set()”_ - no, you can not. Both of those options have the [changeable mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) of `PHP_INI_PERDIR`

Comment: @CBroe “i can fix this by changing the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size with the function ini_set()” - no, you can not. Both of those options have the changeable mode of PHP_INI_PERDIR – CBroe  but you don't tell how to fix the problem  any idea please

Comment: You need to change these options there, where they _can_ be changed. And I already linked to the manual page that _explains_ where that is, in this case - so what more do you need?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution (a fact-based answer) is to set it in `php.ini` file to [avoid any performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000111/which-is-better-php-ini-vs-ini-set). And here is a [useful chapter](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/configuration.changes.php) about configuration of ini variables.

But you cannot update these two parameters by using `ini_set`. Both of those options have the [changeable mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) of `PHP_INI_PERDIR` as CBroe mentionned it in his comment.

For other parameters, if you cannot update your php.ini, this question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. Depending on your web server, you can do it:

- in a `.php.ini` file at the top directory of your project,
- in a `.ht_access` in the public directory,
- in the public/index.php file
- in the Kernel.php